# Kite disabling coc.nvim's completions in this buffer

Tags: neovim

I installed kite to vim and now I get this "error" in red, what is wrong? How can I fix it?:
[image]

y cuando trato de entrar con el arbol de directorios a otro archivo me aparece mas veces, entro a otro archivo con la tecla s:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use coc.nvim and kite-vim together https://github.com/kiteco/vim-plugin/pull/183.

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/coc-kite, you need to uninstall kite-vim first.

Comment: At the moment I am using kite, and sometimes coc, and I followed the steps of a tutorial and there I do not see any error like this

Answer (score 0):

That warning is telling you that CoC is enabled to make suggestions in that extension files, try this in your init.vim

```
autocmd FileType python let b:coc_suggest_disable = 1
```

"autocmd" specify commands to be executed automatically when reading or writing
a file, then you can identify python files using "FileType" and the variable assignation is going to disable CoC suggestions for python files